# PHP 5.3 lambda anonymous function not working

Tags: php, function, lambda

I can't figure out what's wrong here. Here's my test.php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo phpversion();
$arr = array ();

$attrs = array_filter((array)$arr, function($v) {
    return ($v || $v === 0 || $v === '0');
});
```

The output of this script is:

5.3.3 Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /path/test.php on line 8

How can that be? I thought PHP 5.3 supported lambdas.

Comment: It works in my local environment, but in production, I get this. Does anyone have any idea what I would check in my PHP configuration that might be somehow blocking the use of lambdas? Honestly, I can't even believe what I'm seeing. I makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: If I crank down my error reporting to E_ERROR, it works. But that's not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

This was related to a bug in eAccelerator, which had a problem caching opcode that used lambdas. Updated to the latest version of eAccelerator and it is fixed.